# Sqlalchemy sort data based on a specific value (name) and the others as ascending order

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to sort a specific list based on a specific value which is an id that supposed to be on top of the list and the rest would be sorted as ascending order.

Here's the code that I have tried by applying `case`.

```
db_session.query(ListModel)
.order_by(
    case([(ListModel.name == "OHIO", 1)]),
     ListModel.name.asc()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the more standard way to attempt this.  Instead of trying to sort `name` and 1 simultaneously you assign each row either a 1 or 0 if it is Ohio or not and sort by that first, then you sort by the name.  *The order should be `ASC` be default as mentioned in comments.*

```
db.query(ListModel).order_by(
    case([(ListModel.name=='OHIO', 0)], else_=1), 
    ListModel.name)
```

Comment: I think ASC is the default, and that's why using 0, else 1 works.

Comment: @IljaEverilä You are correct, ASC is the default, I updated the answer to reflect your comment.  Thanks.